# Problem with removing element

Tags: jquery

I don't know why this working:

```
 $('.deleteQuestion').live('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/delete_question/' + $(this).attr('name') + '/',
            success: $('[what="question"][name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').remove()                            
        });      
    });
```

but this not working:

```
 $('.deleteQuestion').live('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/delete_question/' + $(this).attr('name') + '/',
            success: function(){$('[what="question"][name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').remove();}                            }
        });      
    });
```

Does someone know?

Comment: Well, what *does* it do and what *is* expected? What debugging has been done? Are there error codes? Does Firebug show the correct request/response? These are things that should be asked of oneself. You can't fix a problem if you don't know what the problem is. Also, the first example *doesn't work as expected* (the element is removed *before* the XHR is even sent!)

Comment: No errors. Sometimes i really don't know what is the problem.

Comment: So keep going down this list: is `success` called? If so, what is `this`? Is `$(thelongexpression)` the expected object? Keep pressing forward removing what *could* be wrong until nothing remains except what is wrong.

Comment: I usually giving as success `alert` or `function(data){alert(data)}` but in this case i got problems because i forget that `$(this)` in success is something else than `$(this)` before success. I apreciate Your advices. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The success callback doesn't operate on the same `this` that the click handler does.  Save it in a variable:

```
$('.deleteQuestion').live('click', function(){
    var element = $(this);
    $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/delete_question/' + $(this).attr('name') + '/',
         success: function(){ //this has to be a function, not a jQuery chain.
              $('[what="question"][name="' + element.attr('name') + '"]').remove();}
         }
    });      
});
```

Comment: And could You tell me what is `$(this)` in `success`, if it is something?

Comment: `this` in the context of `success` is an AJAX event object.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version  `$(this).attr('name')` is evaluated right away.

In the second version `this` is not pointing to the current element since it only gets evaluated when the callback function executes, which is in a different context - so it won't work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this instance neither are working as you intend.

In the first version, you have the following:

```
success: $('[what="question"][name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').remove()
```

This is executed as soon as the line is reached and not on the success callback.

In the 2nd version, you lose the context of this in your callback:

```
success: function(){$('[what="question"][name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').remove();}
```

Also, it looks like you have an additional end brace.

```
remove();}                            }
```

Try the following:

```
$('.deleteQuestion').live('click', function(){
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/delete_question/' + $(this).attr('name') + '/',
            success: function(){$('[what="question"][name="' + $(self).attr('name') + '"]').remove();}
        });      
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is not pointing to what you what in the success function. Try this instead:

```
$('.deleteQuestion').live('click', function() {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/delete_question/' + $(this).attr('name') + '/',
        success: function() {
            $('[what="question"][name="' + $(that).attr('name') + '"]').remove();
        }
    });
});
```